# Django Pagination is not working in ListView

Tags: listview, django-views, pagination

I have a search button that allows user to search for a string in my blog application.  I use a ListView.  Problem is that the paginate_by does not work.  As can be seen in the code there are two other listviews with the same template. The paginate_by does work correctly for those cases. See code below.  The paginate_by works correctly for BlogListView and BlogAuthorListView but not for BlogSearchView. Otherwise BlogSearchView functions correctly.

I tried including MultipleObjectMixin in my class derivation. But that is incompatible with ListView

```
class BlogListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Post
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = '-date_posted'
    paginate_by = 3

class BlogAuthorListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = '-date_posted'
    paginate_by = 3

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-date_posted')

class BlogSearchView( ListView):
    model = Post
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = '-date_posted'
    paginate_by = 3

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        search_text = request.POST.get('search_text')
        posts = Post.objects.filter(Q(content__contains=search_text) | Q(title__contains=search_text))
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'posts': posts, 'search_text': search_text })
```